# WPF ListView and controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program where I use VisualTreeHelper, but it works only with objects which are visible. When I used LogicalTreeHelper, then LTH returns a null value as parent. How to fix it?

```
while (parent.GetType() != typeof(ListViewItem))
        {
            if (parent is Selector)
                break;

            parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
```

I have a ListView with CheckBoxes in one column and must select CB by Name in other column because CB have a one shared event. I must go to parent(ListViewItem) and then go for Name in Col2 where is StackPanel with Image and TextBlock. Is there possibility write Name from col2 to e.g CB Tag as helping value. But I dont want it.

```
enter code here
<ListView>
...
<GridViewColumn Header=" ID" HeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource lvcLeft}" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="cbID" IsChecked="{Binding ID}" **Checked="cbID_Checked"** />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" Name" Width="200"     HeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource lvcLeft}"  >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
...
```

items add:

ListView.items.add(new myItem { ID = false, Name = "abc" });

VisualTreeHelper - return value/object, 
LogicalTreeHelper = return null

but is there any other method how to identify CB when items of ListView are created/loaded at runtime?how to approach checkbox when you want to change the value of IsChecked (some or all). How to hide any column in ListView?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Checking or unchecking a checkbox will call the `ID` property setter on the appropriate `myItem` instance, because you're binding to that propery. That instance knows its own `Name`, so you should be able to do whatever you need to do there. Why do you need to use the `Checked` event at all?